# I need to run one role against groups of hosts behind multiple execution nodes on Ansible Automation Platform without workflows

Tags: ansible, ansible-automation-platform

I have a simple question that I cannot seem to find any documentation on. I have multiple groups of hosts that can only be accessed by different execution nodes. I need to be able to run a role on all hosts at the same time without using workflows and have AAP know to send the jobs to the correct exec nodes. Is this possible or does AAP lack this feature?

I tried workflows and they work but it seems unnecessary. I should be able to inform AAP which hosts can be reached by which exec node without having to set the exec node at the inventory or template level and then leverage workflows.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to use specific execution node is through Instance Groups. In them, you create group of one or more execution nodes and then assign a job template to a group.

RedHat solution 5285681 referes to this particular use-case: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5285681

If you really want to avoid workflows (since you would have multiple instance groups/templates) then the only solution I see would be to create a new template that calls AAP itself and triggers your other template iterating over each instance group.